# join() returning NaN values in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I have some int type values in my series and I tried to join it with a data frame but the series got added as a column but the values are not as expected they are filled with 'NaN'
this is my code

```
s3=Series(np.arange(6))
s3.name="added_series"
np.random.seed(25)
df=DataFrame(np.random.rand(36).reshape((6,6)),index=['r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6'])
dfadd=DataFrame.join(df,s3)
```

[image: Here is the output image]

Comment: The indexes of the dataframe and the series do not match: one is default numerical, and the other is r1, r2, etc.

Comment: Still getting the same NaNs even after changing the column names.

Comment: Column names are OK. The index (row names) of the series differs from the index of the dataframe. Make them the same. Either reset the index of the dataframe or add a non-default index to the series.

Comment: Got it by adding indexes to series. Thank you, But is there no other way in which the values get added without specifying the indexes manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a new column, you don't have to use `join()`.

```py
new_df = df
new_df['added_series'] = list(s3)
```

**Output :**

```py
Out[54]:
0   1   2   3   4   5   added_series
r1  0.870124    0.582277    0.278839    0.185911    0.411100    0.117376    0
r2  0.684969    0.437611    0.556229    0.367080    0.402366    0.113041    1
r3  0.447031    0.585445    0.161985    0.520719    0.326051    0.699186    2
r4  0.366395    0.836375    0.481343    0.516502    0.383048    0.997541    3
r5  0.514244    0.559053    0.034450    0.719930    0.421004    0.436935    4
r6  0.281701    0.900274    0.669612    0.456069    0.289804    0.525819    5
```

Comment: I just tried concatenating the data frame with the series. But thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([df.reset_index(), DataFrame(s3)], axis=1).set_index("index")
```

or using:

```
df.reset_index().join(DataFrame(s3), how="inner").set_index("index")
```

the output is:

```
Out[29]: 
              0         1         2         3         4         5  added_series
index                                                                          
r1     0.870124  0.582277  0.278839  0.185911  0.411100  0.117376             0
r2     0.684969  0.437611  0.556229  0.367080  0.402366  0.113041             1
r3     0.447031  0.585445  0.161985  0.520719  0.326051  0.699186             2
r4     0.366395  0.836375  0.481343  0.516502  0.383048  0.997541             3
r5     0.514244  0.559053  0.034450  0.719930  0.421004  0.436935             4
r6     0.281701  0.900274  0.669612  0.456069  0.289804  0.525819             5
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but is there any way to achieve the same with join().

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Will you please explain the 'how' parameter in join() like when to consider which option.

Comment: You can read this document it's complete and clear:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html